# Turn Off the default play pages

Tags: java, playframework-2.1

We have a play(2.1.2) web-service that handles json. I want to secure it by limiting the access only to the routes specified in the `routes` file. But when I access the root path of the application in the browser, it shows **"Action Not Found"** and shows all the possible routes, I don't want to list the possible routes in the browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shows possible routes only in dev mode. When you run your application like `play start` you will get just "Action Not Found" message with a description "For request 'GET /zxc'".

If you want to override this behavior, try overriding the onHandlerNotFound method on your `Global`:

```
 @Override
 public Result onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
   return Results.notFound(
     views.html.pageNotFound(request.uri())
   );
 }
```

More on this here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGlobal

Comment: Thanks! Its little different for play-2.1.2. I have edited the answer.  See [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGlobal)

Comment: Oh, yes, I didn't notice it is different in play 2.1. Glad you figured it out